# IPSec VPN Client in Java Script using Chrome's "networkingPrivate" API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, vpn

I want to add VPN client support to an existing chrome extension. I noticed that chrome has an API named 'networkingPrivate' for many network configurations. I kick started with a java script that calls some of the methods provided by networkingPrivate API. But, I'm facing chrome.networkingPrivate 'undefined' error. Any reference on how to use the API in a chrome extension would be of great help!

Comment: show code and manifest

Comment: manifest.json

{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "SampleVPN",
  "short_name": "SampleVPN",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "38",

  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icon_16.png",
    "128": "assets/icon_128.png"
  },

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": ["networkingPrivate"]
  }
}

Comment: In main.js, I invoked,

  chrome.networkingPrivate.createNetwork(
      false,  // shared
      { "Type": "VPN",
        "GUID": "TEST_VPN",
        "VPN": {
          "Host": "x.x.x.x",
          "IPsec": {
            "AuthenticationType": "PSK",
            "IKEVersion": "2",
            "PSK": "abc",
            }
          }
      },
      function (result ){
        console.log('result ' + result);
      document.querySelector('#greeting').innerText ='Hello 2';  
      });
};

Comment: not here, on the question itself. see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome OS only, kiosk apps only (not extensions), [dev channel only](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index#dev_apis), and it [is being](https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=%22networkingPrivate+is+being+renamed%22) [renamed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=672186).

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/networking_onc

You probably want [chrome.vpnProvider](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/vpnProvider) instead anyway, but that's still Chrome OS only.

Comment: @ Josh Lee I see. Then, do you have any idea on how the Chrome extensions for VPN service are written?? I came across many such extensions like Palo Alto's https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/globalprotect/nicidmbokaedpmoegdbcebhnchpegcdc?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Comment: 1) That's an app, not extension. 2) It is using chrome.vpnProvider when on ChromeOS. 3) On non-ChromeOS it's using TCP and UDP, which is an app-only permission. 4) Apps on non-ChromeOS are being removed.